# Program linked against libraries that share symbol names runs wrong implementation

Tags: c, linux, static-linking, dynamic-linking

This a bit difficult to understand but I'm doing my best.

On Red Hat 6.4 with gcc 4.4.6 & ld 2.20.51,

I am linking into a binary executable PROGRAM code from one **shared library (.so)** and a **static library (.a)**.

The **shared library** exposes an API invoked directly by PROGRAM. The implementation of this shared library is compiled & linked against a static library **static lib1**.

The **static library** also exposes its own API which is invoked directly by PROGRAM. And some of its implementation is based on a subset of the **static lib1**'s files that were copied directly into it.

None of the APIs (of either library) actually expose a data type or a function implemented by **static lib1**.

Because the code was copied the symbols are identical.

During runtime I see this behaviour:

1. If the order of libraries to the linker is **shared library**, **static library**, then calls to the **shared library API** and calls to the **static library* API will both use the implementation in the **static lib1**.
2. If the order of libraries to the linker is **static library**, **shared library**, then calls to the **shared library API** and calls to the **static library API** will both use the implementation in the **static library 1 - code from lib1 modified**.

[image: Diagram]

How do I get all calls to the static library API to run the implementation in **code from lib 1 modified** and those in the **shared library API** run the implementation in **static lib1**?

Comment: Could you please provide the precise commands used to create (including the "link") the shared library. Also, it would be a lot less confusing if you used actual filenames rather than things like "lib 1 modified". As always, a [mcve] is most helpful.